# Correct use of wait()/notify() for a Tetris game

Tags: java, android, synchronization, tetris

I’m writing a Tetris-like game for Android and I’m trying to implement the “real-time part”. I have something which seems to work, but I want to be sure that my implementation is correct.

What I want is:

- The shapes are going down at a fixed rate (say that I want to wait *n* milliseconds each time the *y* of the shape is decremented)
- The player can drop the shape at any time and the timer waiting for the *n* milliseconds must then be immediately interrupted and start again only for the next shape
- When the shape is droped or when the shape cannot go down anymore, the game waits *m* milliseconds before creating another shape
- The system have to be able to stop the thread at any time

What I am doing is the following (the system can stop the thread with `interrupt()`):

```
class TetrisThread extends Thread {
    private int n = 3000; // for testing purposes, in the real game n will be smaller ;)
    private int m = 1000;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        doDraw();
        while(!interrupted())
        {
            try {
                synchronized (this) {
                    wait(n);
                }
                doPhysics();
                doDraw();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
            }
        }
    }

    // This method is the one which will drop the shape, it is called from another thread
    synchronized public boolean onTouch([…]) {
        […]
        // The shape has to be dropped
        dropShape();
        notify();
        […]
    }

    private void doPhysics() throws InterruptedException {
        […]
        // The shape cannot go down or has been dropped
        sleep(m);
        createNewShape();
        […]
    }
}
```

In particular, the part `synchronized(this) { wait(n); }` looks funny because if I understand correctly this will take a lock on `this` and release it immediately.

But `wait()` requires to be used in a `synchronized(this)` block (why?) and I cannot either synchronize the whole `run()` method, because then if I try to drop three times the shape during the `sleep(m)` call, then the three next shapes will be automatically dropped (which is not what I want).

Does this seem correct to you?
Do you have any correction, advice, or remark?

Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

The `wait()` method is used to make the current running thread to wait the object invoking `wait()` invoke `notify()` (in this case this). The `synchronized(this)` part needed to make sure only one thread at that time accessing `this`.

You can't synchronize the whole run() method, because the run() is from the parent (Thread) class and the parent didn't use synchonized in the declaration.

I don't know how to solve your other problem because I don't get how your program works right now.

Comment: No, I can synchronize the whole _run()_ method, there is no compile nor runtime error. The problem is then that the call to _sleep(m)_ occurs when the locks is hold by _run()_, and the _onTouch()_ method cannot run during that time.  What don’t you understand in the program? The main loop is _wait(n); doPhysics(); doDraw()_, and if the user wants to drop the shape, the _notify()_ call will abort the _wait(n)_ and then call the _sleep(m)_.

Comment: How about having a boolean, that when it's sleeping it's false, and you can't drop the shape, and if it isn't false it can drop it?